# seg faults and kernel panics on fresh install

Tags: boot

System:

Dell XPS 9560 (brand new ssd, I threw out the old one because I thought it was the problem)

Install:

Fresh, unique (not dual boot) full disk encryption using all default Ubuntu 19.10 options (US keyboard)

Problems:

1. Sometimes the system locks itself into read-only mode (dmesg shows invalid checksum on ext4 fs) for no apparent reason. On the next restart, I am presented with initramfs, I hit exit and see /dev/mapper/vgubuntu has somehow been corrupted. `fsck -y /dev/mapper/vgubuntu` appears to fix this problem but it keeps happening and I don't understand why
2. I am frequently presented with errors in the system log about lvm-authentication (and commands like vgs, lead to a seg fault)
3. Anytime I make changes to disk (install software, etc) the next restart has one of the above problems or something similar where it can't mount /sys or /proc and leads to a kernel panic
4. Sometimes, after a restart, the encryption pass will say that it's incorrect when I know with absolute certainty that I am typing in the password correctly. This tends to happen after launching from a live usb or plugging in some other usb device.

A collection of errors that I sometimes see in dmesg:

```
[    0.651560] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.651561] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.651562] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.651563] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.651563] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.651564] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
```

```
[    1.763858] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device: -5
```

```
[    7.648072] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
```

```
[   86.579184] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_GPE.XTBT.SPRT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190703/dswload2-323)
[   86.579191] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [XTBT]
[   86.579192] Initialized Arguments for Method [XTBT]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   86.579193]   Arg0:   0000000046316a7d <Obj>           Integer 000000000000000F
[   86.579196]   Arg1:   000000000e8a068c <Obj>           Integer 0000000001060002
[   86.579198] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190703/psobject-220)
[   86.579200] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE.XTBT due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   86.579203] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE.XTBT due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   86.579207] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._E42 due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   86.579209] ACPI: Marking method _E42 as Serialized because of AE_ALREADY_EXISTS error
[   86.579211] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, while evaluating GPE method [_E42] (20190703/evgpe-511)
```

```
[  127.741599] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
[  127.741601] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
```

```
[  132.597573] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  132.597580] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a11e] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[  132.597585] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

```
[  311.159682] show_signal: 12 callbacks suppressed
[  311.159684] traps: cp[4842] general protection fault ip:7fd3e1a395eb sp:7fff8c268f60 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fd3e1a2d000+22000]
[  311.165259] traps: mv[4852] general protection fault ip:7f0685fba5eb sp:7ffd72e0f060 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f0685fae000+22000]
[  311.165837] traps: mv[4853] general protection fault ip:7fce112145eb sp:7ffcc6cfc6e0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fce11208000+22000]
[  311.167707] traps: cp[4856] general protection fault ip:7f491a6295eb sp:7fff38c88800 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f491a61d000+22000]
[  311.233657] traps: mv[4866] general protection fault ip:7f379fe635eb sp:7ffd5ebbd560 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f379fe57000+22000]
[  311.234862] traps: mv[4867] general protection fault ip:7f89b80a35eb sp:7ffc744939a0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f89b8097000+22000]
[  311.237978] traps: cp[4870] general protection fault ip:7f7de76835eb sp:7fffa43d1310 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f7de7677000+22000]
[  311.244466] traps: mv[4880] general protection fault ip:7f5f4da2b5eb sp:7ffcb4e1df40 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f5f4da1f000+22000]
[  311.244995] traps: mv[4881] general protection fault ip:7f08aa3525eb sp:7fff3ea38990 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f08aa346000+22000]
[  311.246672] traps: cp[4884] general protection fault ip:7fc825b9e5eb sp:7ffeaab5beb0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fc825b92000+22000]
[  494.551262] show_signal: 17 callbacks suppressed
[  494.551264] traps: nautilus[5989] general protection fault ip:7f974d2cd5eb sp:7ffc7e8f6840 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f974d2c1000+22000]
[  494.709609] traps: nautilus[6025] general protection fault ip:7f78f919a5eb sp:7ffe197c5060 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f78f918e000+22000]
[  494.904602] traps: nautilus[6051] general protection fault ip:7fa5143dc5eb sp:7ffdad2aeff0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fa5143d0000+22000]
[  500.109844] traps: systemd-sysctl[6266] general protection fault ip:7f4b4527a5eb sp:7ffe42750720 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f4b4526e000+22000]
[  500.122071] traps: sed[6279] general protection fault ip:7f43647325eb sp:7ffe60bbe830 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f4364726000+22000]
[  500.126567] traps: busctl[6281] general protection fault ip:7ff757e1f5eb sp:7ffd4cc4f6c0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7ff757e13000+22000]
[  502.161144] traps: systemd-sysctl[6352] general protection fault ip:7f44b3d845eb sp:7ffc50bd2ab0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f44b3d78000+22000]
[  502.176836] traps: sed[6362] general protection fault ip:7fb4dc0ab5eb sp:7fff3294aa30 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fb4dc09f000+22000]
[  502.179966] traps: busctl[6364] general protection fault ip:7fb8f93395eb sp:7ffe0e5bb7f0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7fb8f932d000+22000]
[  504.205440] traps: systemd-sysctl[6422] general protection fault ip:7ff1f6e875eb sp:7ffee41a8cb0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7ff1f6e7b000+22000]
[  504.245245] traps: sed[6445] general protection fault ip:7f56bf3965eb sp:7ffd170158a0 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f56bf38a000+22000]
[  504.247926] traps: busctl[6448] general protection fault ip:7f76866525eb sp:7ffee3dd5880 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f7686646000+22000]
[  504.302730] traps: mv[6470] general protection fault ip:7f5add4545eb sp:7ffe2fdcd470 error:0 in ld-2.30.so[7f5add448000+22000]
```

A collection of boot errors:

Comment: You've given clues (read-only has a cause; you look up the logs before that for reason!).  Have you validated the health of your HDD/SSD?, check the health of your PSU (devices can malfunction when given dirty power), or are you using specific ports (eg. USB3 when you have issues, ie. drawing more poer which causes the PSU to struggle & fail..)  What did the old SSD record as reason for errors/poor-health?  or was it PSU you ignored?  Have you explored your PSU and the power it provides?   (variation? within-spec?  etc), replace cables, clean contacts etc

Comment: The cause of the read-only is not clear. `dmesg` returns something about ext4-fs checksum value. It's a laptop, so not sure how to go about checking PSU. The error doesn't seem to care if it's attached to plug, usb-c or running on battery. It's been happening on all of the above situations.

Comment: Stupid question, but you *do* have the most up to date BIOS for your system installed yes?  Sometimes a BIOS update on Dell systems can fix some of these problems.

Comment: Not a stupid question. I upgraded to new version about a week ago, then couldn't get through a live usb install at all, so downgraded and now I'm having a bunch of problems (better than not being able to complete an install)